# how to share a common data structure among various controller of an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application with several controllers and views. As a user navigates through various vies and controller i need to record the navigation history for back tracking purpose. for this purpose i have decided to use a stack for pushing and popping the navigation history as i move from controller to controller. the problem is after trying a lot of stuff like

```
static class with static properties, HttpContext.Applicaion property,
HttpContext.Cache property  and also the HttContext.Current.Session property
```

but each time i move from controller to controller these properties are nullified and a new instance is created in each case.(fro going from controller to controller I am using 
RedirectToAction() method

What i need is an stack that is available throughout the application and i can use it from different controllers to get or set the navigation info.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is actually state less.

However in your case storing the navigation history in the Session could be a good fit.

You don't want the navigation history to be stored in the HttpContext.Application because the history will be store on the application level. This means that all users will have access to this data if you are displaying that data in a view. I think that in your case you are interested in storing the navigation information for each user individually. That why it better to use the Session.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use some kind of database, either SQL or noSQL.  It is more reliable than using Session, especially if you need to support load balancing.